# How to check whether profile Id permissions and accordingly redirect to authorize page using Facebook.Rest.Api?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-rest-api

For a given profile ID, I need to post a message from my site.  I created a facebook app  using `Facebook.Rest.Api` API.  I was successful in posting but for IDs which are not authorised I want to redirect to the authorise login page.

```
(window.top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://XXXX.com&scope=publish_stream";)
```

I am checking whether the user already gave permission using Facebook Connect, and then using above code to show login page in case the profile ID is not still permitted. So I expect login page, but instead it bypasses that and shows the redirect url.

If I try separately without connecting to facebook for checking permission it works fine.
Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So the SDK/Facebook knows when to ask the user for permision to do something by what you pass into the Perms setting.
If you need to post to there feed add the permission "publish_stream" to the CanvasAuthorizer like this.

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Perms = "user_about_me,publish_stream" };
```

Then is is just a matter of checking if the user authorized that access.

```
    if (auth.Authorize())
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient(auth.Session.AccessToken);
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "Test App Message";
        parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
        parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
        parameters.name = "Test App Article Title";
        parameters.caption = "Test App Caption for the link";
        parameters.description = "Test App Longer description of the link";
        parameters.actions = new
        {
            name = "View on Zombo",
            link = "http://www.zombo.com",
        };
        dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
    }else
    {
        //code what to do if the user does not give you publish Perms
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still I could not do?

Comment: I want asp.net 2.0/visual studio 2005 based sample code for this. I am able to do it using twitter API each user will be provided with access token and access secret and i could ask user only one time authorization of twitting and successfully posted to his twitter. Same way how could i do it with respect to facebook - means only one time authorization and sending post next time onwards Can I have a sample code also. I know so many articles/documentation/forums but i am missing something somewhere Could you kindly help me?

Comment: As far as i know the Facebook C# SDK requires Net Framework 3.5 or greater. Per the CodePlex site.System Requirements
For Use

.Net Framework 3.5
.Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile
.Net Framework 4.0
.Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile
Silverlight 4
Windows Phone 7
For Development

Visual Studio 2010